# Concept of "Excel [Blank] Cell" in any programming language?

Tags: parsing, types, compiler-construction, grammar, language-design

Excel has a Blank cell which has some interesting properties when it comes to calculations:

In the below we will assume cell **A1** is blank.

- A blank cell equals another blank cell: `=A1=A1`.
- A blank cell equals `''`, `0`, and `FALSE`: `=A1=""`, `=A1=0`, `=A1=FALSE`.
- A blank cell will coerce to the expected operand type: `=A1+A1` (0), `=-A1` (0), `=A1&A1` ("").

I suppose the closest item I've found is the `bool` function in python, which covers the first two cases above:

- `bool(None) == bool(None)`
- `bool(None) == bool(0)`, `bool(None) == bool('')`, `bool(None) == bool(False)`

But that doesn't cover the third case where it implicitly casts to the expected type. Is there anything in a language that covers that?

---

Here is a video showing some of the properties: https://gyazo.com/b23989ba1fd28500aff32a6b6cb6dca5.

Comment: It's vaguely similar to Awk's idiosyncratic coercion rules, which are a known source of subtle bugs. (Sometimes even produced by people like me, with a long-standing fondness for Awk.)

Comment: @rici what would be an example of an Awk coercion rule like that? Mainly with equality checking or what?

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking of comparisons, not just equality. In Awk, all comparison operators use the same coercion rules. But it's not contextual, so I not sure it's really relevant to your question.

Comment: Interesting. What exactly you are looking for? Any function in any language that follows the logic? What is the end goal?

Comment: I gave an answer based on the three statements but then in reading the example you gave for Python it seems you are implying more than you ask with the three statements, specifically that the language is statically typed, if so then please state that and I will remove my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there anything in a language that covers that?

Short answer:

Languages that support [syntactic unification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_(computer_science)#Syntactic_unification_of_first-order_terms), e.g. Prolog, Datalog, Answer Set Programming, ... .
These programming languages are typically [Logic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_programming) languages.

---

---

Here are demonstrations of your list using [SWI-Prolog](https://www.swi-prolog.org/)

Note: In Prolog [=](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=%3D/2) is unification not comparison [==](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(%3D%3D)/2). In some situations if you think of a variable as a named pointer and unification as setting pointers equal it makes sense but that analogy works only in specific cases, you have been warned.

---

- A blank cell equals another blank cell: =A1=A1.

```
?- A = B.
A = B.
```

Now if A is bound to a value then B is also bound because they are unified.

```
?- A = B,A=1.
A = B, B = 1.
```

---

- A blank cell equals '', 0, and FALSE: =A1="", =A1=0, =A1=FALSE.

I will take that to mean that a blank cell has a [primitive data type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_data_type) with a default value of that type.

Since Prolog is not [strongly typed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_and_weak_typing) a variable has no type until a value is [bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables) to the variable, think Python with [Duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing). Even then the concept of a specific type may not be what one expects.

However when the second statement is considered with the third statement

- A blank cell will coerce to the expected operand type: =A1+A1 (0), =-A1 (0), =A1&A1 ("").

then as noted the Prolog variable (Excel blank cell) acquires the type upon binding.

```
?- (var(B)->write('B is variable');write('B is not variable')),nl,(integer(B)->write('B is integer');write('B is not integer')),nl,A is 2,(integer(A)->write('A is integer');write('A is not integer')),nl,A=B,(integer(B)->write('B is integer');write('B is not integer')).
B is variable
B is not integer
A is integer
B is integer
B = A, A = 2.
```

Answer (score 0):

- A blank cell in Excel is not a `data type` but it is an object with multiple parameters.
- Blank cell equals depend on the blank cell and the other value or cell type.
- Remember that an empty cell in Excel could be a `date` or `currency` or `Boolean`

So the closest thing to Excel's blank cell is really **'null'** in most programming languages. a blank cell is state rather than data type.

Comment: Would it be correct to say that it is null in most weakly typed languages? As in a strongly typed language the null value still has a specific type.

Comment: Yes, it is null in most loosely typed languages.

Comment: @user16930239 sure but usually `null` would produce `null` when compared with anything else (I'm thinking more in the sql sense) or are you thinking of a particular language in particular that uses `null` differently than that?

Comment: @David542 in that case, I wonder if `Void` might a better analogy?

Comment: @Fogmeister I see, for example in what language, javascript? c? etc.

Comment: @David542 I'm not sure. Just interested in the discussion. 