# Possible to store a `0000-00-00` (identity) value as a date?

Tags: sql, datetime

I sometimes find it useful having a "zero-value" that is not-null for operations such as `Date1 + Date2`. This can be done with a `TIME` value easily, something like `TIME 01:02:03 + TIME 00:00:00` so it acts as an identity value. Is there the possibility to use an identity value for the date/datetime/timestamp types, or is that not possible in the SQL statement/implementations?

Comment: No, it’s not (at least probably not in most mainstream databases). 00:00:00 is an actual time whereas 0000-00-00 is not an actual date

Comment: In our calendar, C.E. 1 follows immediately after 1 B.C.E. with no intervening year zero. So... there is no year 0, no month 0, and no day_of_month 0, so no, it's unlikely that in any RDBMS, this would be supported.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to add dates. What is `1st March 2002 + 29 November 2023`? It only makes sense to add an interval (timespan) to a date.

Comment: @MartinSmith right, but subtracting dates is often useful, and with an identity value it acts as 0.

Comment: @David542 You are confusing 'point in time' with 'duration'. Subtracting two points in time gives a duration. Unlike point in time, a duration can be zero and even negative. Types `datetime` and `date` are not designed to hold durations, as explained by Matt.

Comment: Simple example: a `date` column cannot hold a duration of 90 days, which might be required as input for calculation of contract expirations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few things:

- `0000-00-00` would be interpreted as: Year = 0, Month = 0, Day = 0
- There is no month 0 or day 0 in either the Gregorian or ISO 8601 calendar system.
- There is a year 0 in the ISO 8601 calendar system, but not in the Gregorian calendar system.
- Regardless of calendar, the ANSI SQL standard for the `DATE` type sets the range from `0001-01-01` to `9999-12-31` (CE).  Most databases comply with this  part of the standard (see [note for MS SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/data-types/date-transact-sql#ansi-and-iso-8601-compliance), for example)

  - Note, even though Oracle SQL supports a larger range, it still does not support a year zero.

Thus in the general case, it is not possible to use a date of `0000-00-00` in most SQL database systems.  Likewise, the date `0001-00-00` would also be invalid, in most cases.

*However*, for every rule there is an exception.  It appears that MySQL has two special zero-date modes. [From the MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/using-date.html):

> MySQL permits you to store dates where the day or month and day are zero. This is convenient if you want to store a birthdate in a `DATE` column and you know only part of the date. To disallow zero month or day parts in dates, enable the `NO_ZERO_IN_DATE` mode.
>
> MySQL permits you to store a "zero" value of `'0000-00-00'` as a "dummy date." This is in some cases more convenient than using `NULL` values. If a date to be stored in a `DATE` column cannot be converted to any reasonable value, MySQL stores `'0000-00-00'`. To disallow `'0000-00-00'`, enable the `NO_ZERO_DATE` mode.

Personally, I wouldn't use these - but they are available.

Additionally:

- `DATE` + `DATE` is illogical.  For example, what would 2020-12-31 + 2023-03-07 be?  There's no way to combine these values that retains the intended purpose of a *date*
- `TIME` + `TIME` is only logical if the `TIME` objects you're using refer to a *duration*.  For example, 3 minutes + 5 minutes = 7 minutes.  However, if the objects refer to *time of day*, then the operation is illogical.  11:00 AM + 8:00 PM has no logical answer.  (You can *subtract* them though.)

  - This varies between database systems.  In MySQL, the `TIME` type is a duration ranging from -838:59:59.000000 to 838:59:59.000000.  But in MS SQL Server, the `TIME` type is a time-of-day, ranging from 00:00:00.0000000 to 23:59:59.9999999.

Comment: Great answer, though perhaps a better example in my question would be `DATE` - `DATE` to get the difference between two dates.

Comment: @David what is the "difference" between 2023-03-08 and (`NULL` or (no date) or `0000-00-00`, the subject of your [nearly 3000th, congrats] question)?

Comment: @CodeCaster a dubious distinction, no doubt! This is maybe an esoteric thing, but we have an application that produces a dynamic type similar to an Excel blank value -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74946299/concept-of-excel-blank-cell-in-any-programming-language. So something like `1+@blank` should produce `1` (@blank = 0) and something like `DATE "2014-01-01" + @blank` should produce `DATE "2014-01-01"` (@blank = interval 0 year). There's no signature for BINARY_ADD(DATE, DATE) in any language, so my question was a bit poorly constructed, but anyways, it's to produce a '0-value' entry.

Comment: ...of the type of the signature for the operator.

Comment: @CodeCaster finally, I think mysql does support this zero-date thing: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/using-date.html.

Answer (score 3):

> I sometimes find it useful having a "zero-value" that is not-null for operations such as Date1 + Date2

That is not useful. Do not use "sentinel values" to make your programming seemingly easier.

You then later have to explain yourself (or the next developer) why you use the "date" 0000-00-00 throughout the system. Or when that doesn't work, you start using 1900-01-01, which then during solving an issue appears to be a valid birth or purchase or manufacture date.

`NULL` exists for a reason, and so does `if ()`. Use them where appropriate, and don't add dates.

Comment: We don't want to accidentally trigger y0k

Answer (score -1):

Read the fun manual.  Use 0001-01-01 instead!  There is no zero month or zero date.  Year starts counting at 1.

[image]